# SetSelected between 5 buttons in a relative layout

Tags: android

I have 5 buttons in a `RelativeLayout` aligned `layout_centerHorizontal = true` next to each other.
I have different states mentioned in a `drawable` which maintains different states such as `pressed`, `focused` and `unfocused`.
My question is If I `onClick` on button1, `button1.setSelected = true`. The button has full focus. Now when I navigate to button2 and perform click on button2, how to remove the existing `setSelected` and call setSelected for button2.

Answer (score 0):

That seems more like a logic problem to me, try to solve future logic problems by yourself in order to become a better programmer.

Anyways a quick solution for me would be

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(HomeFragment()), View.OnClickListener {

   private val buttonList = ArrayList<Int>()

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       buttonList.add(binding.button1.id)
       binding.button1.setOnClickListener(this)

       buttonList.add(binding.button2.id)
       binding.button2.setOnClickListener(this)

       buttonList.add(binding.button3.id)
       binding.button3.setOnClickListener(this)
   }

   override fun onClick(v: View?) {
       buttonList.forEach { buttonId ->
           button.isSelected = buttonId == v?.id
       }
   }

}
```